# python-docx: 'package not found'

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a doc.docx file at '/var/code/oa'. I need to read it use python-docx. 
I write this:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('/var/code/oa/doc.docx')
```

then, have error.. 
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at '/var/code/oa/doc.docx'

why?

Thanks @soon. 
Uh, It's stupid. the reason is the file, it's must be `docx` file. 
I just change the file name from `doc` to `docx`, it's not a really `docx` file.

Comment: Are you sure this is valid `docx` file? Could you, please, check this file using function `is_zipfile` from module `zipfile`?

Comment: If there still is error, please tell me.

Comment: @soon uh, I just change the filename from doc to docx. it's the problem?

Comment: @soon :( It's really the problem.

Answer (score 9):

If there is nothing in your doc.docx, it will raise PackageNotFoundError. Try to put something in it and do it again. Meanwhile, an invalid docx file will cause this error too. Tell me if it works.

Comment: It has more content, has one table.

Comment: Thank u very much and it's fixed. The problem is the file, it is not a really 'docx' file. --!

Comment: @dsphoebe Yeah. Since you don't answer soon, I thought it didn't work for you. I've updated my answer. You can accept it so that anyone else could find this answer easily. Thanks!

Comment: Check the path as well, the error (same as OP) is misleading if the path is wrong I lost too many hours with this...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answers, `'package not found'` error also occurs:

If the docx file is already opened in the windows, while running the python program. **So closing all the docx files, restarting the kernel and running the python program again might also solve the error.**

The error is also caused **If the program is running in any other softwares except Windows (Linux, Ubuntu, ...  ).**

Comment: Sometimes when the word document is open in word there is no error, and sometimes I get a page not found error.  I am not sure why, just wanted to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

The other reason for this error is absence of file stream or file object not created. So following code should be one of the alternative fix.

```
file_ref = open("/var/code/oa/doc.docx","rb")
doc = docx.Document(file_ref)
```